# Grid with api 21

Tags: android, xml

it's supposed to be a 2*2 gridlayout but it shows only 2 elements whatever I do on api 21 (These two elements are the latter c0,r1 and c1,r1)
where is the problem?!
tried to edit the column Weight & row weight 
tried to change gridlayout height
tried to change cardview layout_gravity 
but none of them worked

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:rowCount="2">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_gravity="fill|top|right"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0">



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_gravity="fill|top|left"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0">



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_gravity="fill|bottom|right"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_gravity="fill|bottom|left"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
```

[screenshot for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jv2o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2*2 `GridLayout` but you can't see them
try to use `<ScrollView>` in top of your `GridLayout`
then you can scroll and see your 2*2 `GridLayout`

**Like This**

```
<ScrollView>
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:rowCount="2">
     .
     .
     .
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope to Help you

Comment: I discover the problem it wasn't in the code but it was in avd itself but when a tried the app on external device it worked just fine :)